# Limitations of geometric networks in ArcMap (Cost Calculation)

Tags: arcmap, network, geometric-network, least-cost

I am working with a point dataset and a street network within a geographic region.
This region is divided in sub-divisions for which I want to calculate single networks within their area.
Every single sub-division has a network with consumer-points and a center to which I want to calculate the distance and the costs for each consumer.

I added a screenshot from my data. Brown points are consumers with different values which are dependant on the distance to the black centers (squares).

Does anyone has an idea how to calculate such things with a geometric network, or is there a better solution to do that?
[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the Network Analyst extension to try and do this?

Comment: yes, i did that. Unfortunately the tool cant set the sinks right.